Why any irreducible unitary representation of an abelian Lie group is one-dimensional?
Assume that $A$ is an Abelian Lie group. Is there a reference for this fact "any of its irreducible unitary representations is one-dimensional and takes the form $$R:A\to \mathbb{C}^*: \alpha\mapsto e^{ip(\alpha)}$$ for some fixed element $p\in A^*$"? Is this a theorem?

I don't know whether this theorem possesses a specific name, but it can be proven with the help of Schur's lemma. Let's recall that a representation is a homomorphism $R : A \to GL(\Bbb{C})$. Since $A$ is abelian, we have thus $R(a)R(b) = R(ab) = R(ba) = R(b)R(a)$ $\forall a,b \in A$, hence $(R(a) - \lambda I_n)R(b) = R(b)(R(a) - \lambda I_n)$ $\forall\lambda \in \Bbb{C}$ (because the identity matrix commutes with all matrices). Choosing $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue of $R(a)$, we deduce that $R(a) - \lambda I_n = 0$ thanks to Schur's lemma, hence $R(a) = \lambda I_n$. If $n = \operatorname{deg} R(a) > 1$, then $R(a) = \lambda \oplus \ldots \oplus \lambda$, meaning that $R(a)$ is reducible, that is why $n = 1$ and $R(a) = \lambda$ in the end.
Now, since $R$ is a unitary irreducible representation (and every representation is similar to a unitary irrep actually), $\lambda$ belongs to the unit circle, in such a way that $R$ can be reparametrized as $R(a) = e^{ip(a)}$, with $p : A \to \Bbb{R}$. Finally, given that $R$ is homomorphic, i.e. $R(ab) = R(a)R(b)$, the map $p$ must satisfy $p(ab) = p(a+b)$, so that $p \in A^*$.

Thank you very much for your nice explanation. I got it well now. Appreciate your help.

Could you please agive me a referenece for Schur's Lemma?

@Mahtab Schur's Lemma is in every text on Lie algebras. For example, see these lecture notes, $1.2.30$.

@DietrichBurde Yes. Thank you very much foe the link.
